# current sensing board/adapter (low current)

Tags: current, oscilloscope, sensing

I'm trying to find a well designed current sensing board which is intended to be used with an oscilloscope.

The closest thing i found is the [ucurrent](https://www.eevblog.com/projects/ucurrent/) which is meant for multimeters, low cost breakout boards with a shunt and amplifier on it (e.g. sparkfun) and some other amplifier demo boards by chip vendors.

I know there are inductive current probes (clamp on line), but most of them are either only AC or meant for higher currents. Also they are quite pricey.

I could build my own using shunts and an amplifiers. But aren't their any commercial (professional, calibrated) boards/devices available?

My feature whishlist includes high bandwith, selectable sensitivity, dedicated ac/dc outputs...

Thanks for any pointers and suggestions!

Edit: 
In my particular case the current is something below 30mA. But i also want to measure AC components of the current in a uA range and a frequency of about 100Khz - 20Mhz.
I am looking for a pcb with multiple/selectable shunt resistors, amplifier configurations and filters. 
So e.g. one channel for DC in the mA range and one filtered AC channel with higher resolution.

Comment: You need a sense resistor, not a 'current sensing board' for doing a current measurement.   The resistors are very different for 200A and 10 pA currents, of course.

Comment: With the board i meant a pcb that has multiple shunt resistors that can be selected via jumpers and multiple amplifiers with different specs.

Comment: With two 10:1 probes, and differential measurement mode on the o'scope, it just takes a box of shunt resistors.  Biggest problem: routing wires to the device under test.

Comment: I want to measure at the DUT supply. The problem with measuring the voltage across the shunts directly is, that since the shunts need to be small in order to not influence the voltage much, one needs to amplify that voltage in order to get it to a usable range.

Comment: Amplifiers.  Calibrated amplifiers: that's what the oscilloscope has.

Answer (score 2):

the answer depends on your definition of "low current".

a typical I-V converter, with minimum impact on the circuitry it is inserted into, can be done by an opamp. a lowly NE5532 would work most of the time.

with a slightly fancier opamp (TL0xx, TDA1308, or the higher end LMCs), you can get into the na or pa range fairly easily. I have built TL074-based nanoammeter and LMC6042/6062-based picoammeters. here is a good starting point at my blog: https://dannyelectronics.wordpress.com/2016/02/19/an-inexpensive-and-easy-to-build-picoammeter/

the resistors become expensive, and the construction more non-normal.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, your blog post would be a good start for rolling my own circuit. I just hoped someone already did the engineering and sells a (maybe more non-normal :) ) board that implements a couple of solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Current shunt IC's are pretty common but the common mode voltage, gain, and bandwidth can be an issues, since you did not specify.

Typically a 50mV shunt is used for low voltage  or 0.1 % of the voltage, whichever is bigger then either a low CM input input that amplifies small signals near/below gnd as V- for single supply or near Vcc.  that's ok for Neutral or DC return shunts but with residential line AC voltages that won't easily work unless you are simply using a floating DMM to measure the series voltage drop.

A universal intrusive solution for a given range and bandwidth, can be designed at extra complexity and cost like a lab instrument, but it would be more practical first to define explicity your specs. ok?

[IC's](http://www.digikey.com/products/en/integrated-circuits-ics/pmic-current-regulation-management/734?k=current%20sense&pkeyword=current%20sense)

Comment: I was thinking of having a 1 - 10 Ohms shunt and a bigger shunt in parallel, with a series capacitor to filter out DC components. And then two amplifiers with different gains across the shunts.

Comment: sure, as long as you satisfy the CM input range

Answer (score 0):

Use a common-base bipolar. The emitter connects to 100 ohm to GND. Base goes to 1KOhm pot wiper. Collector to 1,000 ohms to +5v. Place 0.1uF from Shunt to the emitter. Adjust the pot for 2.6 volts across the 1Kohm, which tells us there is 2.6mA thru the transistor, its GM is 0.1 amp/volt, and the gain is GM*Rc = 0.1 * 1,000 == 100X. You'll likely get 15 or 20MHz bandwidth, with a DC_blocking High-pass-filter set by Cin and Rin, or 0.1uF and 10 ohms, or 159KHz lower corner. Bigger cap, lower DC_block corner frequency.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQVrRY.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>